# Jenkins DSL generic multiple promotions

Tags: groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I've written most of our project's jobs/pipelines in DSL without any previous groovy experience but now I'm stuck at more advanced problem that I can't figure out.

I'm trying to implement a method that would add 1,2,n promotions to a job.
Below you can see a fully-working method that can add one promotion, and I expected it to work in such way that I'd just call the method twice if I needed another one but then I ran into my problem - only promotion that was created the latest would be generated.

```
/** 
    * @param job           DSL job object
    * @param promotionName Name of the promotion
    * @param nextJobs      Comma seperated string of jobs to trigger when promotion is executed
    * @param deployers     Comma seperated string IDs that can execute promotion
    * @param params        Array of parameters to pass to the next job [0] = key, [1] = value.
*/
static void addPromotion(def job, String promotionName, String nextJobs, String deployers, String[][] params){
        job.properties {
            promotions {
                promotion {
                    name(promotionName)
                    icon("star-gold")
                    conditions {
                        manual(deployers)
                    }
                    actions {
                        downstreamParameterized {
                            trigger(nextJobs) {
                                parameters {
                                    for (String[] param : params){
                                        predefinedProp(param[0]+"=",param[1])
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The way it would work, however, if I added another 'promotion' closure like this, however, this example would generate almost identical(name and name-1) promotions:

```
static void addPromotion(def job, String promotionName, String nextJobs, String deployers, String[][] params){
        job.properties {
            promotions {
                promotion {
                    name(promotionName)
                    icon("star-gold")
                    conditions {
                        manual(deployers)
                    }
                    actions {
                        downstreamParameterized {
                            trigger(nextJobs) {
                                parameters {
                                    for (String[] param : params){
                                        predefinedProp(param[0]+"=",param[1])
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                promotion {
                    name("${promotionName}-1")
                    icon("star-gold")
                    conditions {
                        manual(deployers)
                    }
                    actions {
                        downstreamParameterized {
                            trigger(nextJobs) {
                                parameters {
                                    for (String[] param : params){
                                        predefinedProp(param[0]+"=",param[1])
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to re-use closures in some way and populate the variables from a different method maybe? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Yes it is possible, the Groovy way of doing this would be to add your promotions to a list a iterate over that list that invoking the necessary job-dsl that you need to run. I will provide a full answer to this over the weekend.

Comment: I managed to come up with a solution that is similar to what you said, but I use objects instead. However, feel free to provide Groovy way of doing it for the aesthetic and learning.

Comment: Been a crazy week! Apols for not answering yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved it.

Generic promotion object part:

```
/**
* Adds 'promoted-builds' plugin configuration to job
**/
class Promotions {


    public def    job
    public String promotionName
    public String nextJobs
    public String deployers
    public String [][] params

     /** 
    * @param job           DSL job object
    * @param promotionName Name of the promotion
    * @param nextJobs      Comma seperated string of jobs to trigger when promotion is executed
    * @param deployers     Comma seperated string IDs that can execute promotion
    * @param params        Array of parameters to pass to the next job [0] = key, [1] = value.
    */

    public Promotions(Object jobName, String promotionName, String nextJobs, String deployers, String[][] params){
        this.job = jobName
        this.promotionName = promotionName
        this.nextJobs = nextJobs
        this.deployers = deployers
        this.params = params
    }

    static void addPromotions(Promotions ... jobPromotions){
        // Assuming the same job is provided as arguments
        jobPromotions[0].job.properties {
            promotions {
                for (Promotions jobPromotion : jobPromotions){
                    promotion {
                        name(jobPromotion.promotionName)
                        // star-gold, star-silver
                        icon("star-gold")
                        conditions {
                            manual(jobPromotion.deployers)
                        }
                        actions {
                            downstreamParameterized {
                                trigger(jobPromotion.nextJobs) {
                                    parameters {
                                        for (String[] param : jobPromotion.params){
                                            predefinedProp(param[0],param[1])
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then I prepare my params and pass them to the promotion constructor, and in the end I call addPromotions() and pass all my constructed objects to it:

```
    def nextJobs   = "${Configuration.repoName}-${branchName}-deploy-to-perf"        
    def deployers  = "developer"
    def params     = [["VERSION", "\${VERSION}"],
                     ["SOURCE_GIT_COMMIT", "\${SOURCE_GIT_COMMIT}"]] as String[][]
    def promo1 = new Promotions(job, "Promote to PERF", nextJobs, deployers, params)


    def nextJobs2   = "../master/${Configuration.repoName}-${branchName}-to-prod-dtr"        
    def deployers2  = "admin"
    def params2     = [["VERSION", "\${VERSION}"],
                      ["SOURCE_GIT_COMMIT", "\${SOURCE_GIT_COMMIT}"]] as String[][]
    def promo2 = new Promotions(job, "Promote to PROD", nextJobs2, deployers2, params2)

    Promotions.addPromotions(promo1, promo2)
```

Comment: This is a fine answer.